# Как сделать загрузку нескольких img в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть вот такой вот код загрузки img:
routes/web.php

```
Route::get('imageupload','ImageController@imageUpload');
Route::post('imageupload','ImageController@imageUploadPost');
```

Контроллер:

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{   
public function imageUpload()
{
    return view('imageupload');
}
public function imageUploadPost(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

    return back()
        ->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.')
        ->with('path',$imageName);
}        }
```

Вьюха:

```
<div class="panel-body">

                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </div>
            <img src="/images/{{ Session::get('path') }}">
        @endif

        <form action="{{ url('imageupload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="file" name="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            <form action="{{ url('imageupload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="file" name="image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Загружает только один img... Что мне мне нужно исправить, чтоб загрузить несколько картинок одновременно?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите загрузить, какие 2 img. Ваш код  имеет только 1 img `<img src="/images/{{ Session::get('path') }}">`

Comment: Или вы upload имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что у меня 2 поля ввода для картинок(файлов)...

Answer (score 2):

Сама форма будет выглядеть так:

```
 <form action="{{ url('imageupload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="file" name="images[]" />
                <input type="file" name="images[]" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

А контроллер, скорее всего, как то так должен выглядеть :

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function imageUpload()
    {
        return view('imageupload');
    }

    public function imageUploadPost(Request $request)
    {
        $paths = [];
        foreach($request->images as $image) {


            $this->validate($image, [
                'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);

            $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
            $paths[] = $imageName;
        }


        return back()
            ->with('success', 'Image Uploaded successfully.')
            ->with('paths', $paths);
    }
}
```

Comment: а как на имеющий контроллер подставить это?

Comment: @JhonGhoult так описал же imageUploadPost или в чем вопрос?